# Click VS. Tapped

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I know the "difference", but what exactly is the point?

I made an app. A button implements both Click and Tapped. I have a Touchscreen PC (yay I bought it yesterday!), and I tapped the button with my finger (when I had only implemented Click handler) - and it worked. I then implemented Tapped handler, and I then clicked the button with my mouse. And it worked.

So, both work in both scenarios.

Is Click only to be used for backwards compatibility? That's the only reason I can think of to use both. But my question is, do we need to have both handlers for every interaction in our apps?

Comment: Instead of Click Handler and Tap Handler, create a proper ViewModel and Put a `Command` and Bind the `Button.Command` to that Command in the ViewModel.